# Next.js: Correct way to get dynamic route param when change triggered by Next.Link

Tags: next.js

I have a kanban app build with Next.js. I currently have two boards:

```
{"name": "New Board", "id": "6db0ceec-d371-4b53-8065-2eeebac4694a"}
{"name": "tired": "cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a"}
```

I have a menu which maps over next `Link`, rendering links like so:

```
<Link href={`/board/${board.id}`}>{board.name}</Link>
```

I then have the following:

- `src/pages/board/[boardId].js` (page)
- `src/pages/api/board/[boardId].js` (API end point)

In the page, I've defined an async function which sends a `GET` request to the end point that retrieves the data. For SSR, it's called in `getServerSideProps()` (this would be called when a user navigates to a specific board page from another part of the app). For client-side, I call this in an effect. (This is called when the user is already on the board page but they select a different board from the menu).

The issue I am having is figuring out the correct Next.js idiomatic way to get the new `id` from the route when it is changed. I've tried using  `router.query` and `router.asPath`. However, it often gives me the *old* value (before the route changed). The only way I am reliably able to get the correct param when the route changes is to use `window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]`.

I will include the source code for the page as well as some console.log() output which will show how the three methods of getting the id from the route are inconsistent (window is always correct) as I switch back and forth between the two boards by clicking the `Links` in the menu:

```
// src/pages/board/[boardId].js

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import supabase from 'Utilities/SupabaseClient'
import Board from 'Components/Screens/Board/Board'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios'
import { getBaseUrl } from 'Utilities'
import { hydrateTasks } from 'Redux/Reducers/TaskSlice'

const BoardPage = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  async function handleRouteChange() {
    const { asPath } = router
    const { boardId } = router.query // sometimes this does not update!
    const idFromWindow = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]
    const { board, tasks } = await handleFetchData({boardId: idFromWindow})
    console.log(`hello from handleRouteChange:\n\nFrom window: ${idFromWindow}\n\nFrom router.query: ${boardId}\n\nFrom router.asPath: ${asPath}`)
    dispatch(hydrateTasks({board, tasks}))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    //subscribe
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
    //unsubscribe
    return () => router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
  }, [ router.events]);

  return (
    <Board {...props}/>
  )
}

const handleFetchData = async ({boardId, req}) => {
  const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(req)
  return axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/board/${boardId}`)
    .then(({data}) => data)
    .catch(err => { console.log(err)})
}

export async function getServerSideProps ({ query, req }) {
  const { user } = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req)
  if (!user) {
    return { props: {}, redirect: { destination: '/signin' } }
  }

  const { boardId } = query
  const { board, tasks}  = await handleFetchData({boardId, req})
  return { props: { user, board, tasks } }
}

export default BoardPage
```

Starting from the "tired" board, I click back and forth between "New Board" and "tired". Observe the console output. The window is always correct. The router is frequently wrong:

```
// click 1
[boardId].js?0a51:19 hello from handleRouteChange:

From window: 6db0ceec-d371-4b53-8065-2eeebac4694a

From router.query: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.asPath: /board/cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

// click 2
[boardId].js?0a51:19 hello from handleRouteChange:

From window: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.query: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.asPath: /board/cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a


// click 3
[boardId].js?0a51:19 hello from handleRouteChange:

From window: 6db0ceec-d371-4b53-8065-2eeebac4694a

From router.query: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.asPath: /board/cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

// click 4
[boardId].js?0a51:19 hello from handleRouteChange:

From window: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.query: cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a

From router.asPath: /board/cc41d33e-43a1-49bd-8b76-18e46417b27a
```

I'm new to Next.js, so it's possible I am going about this the wrong way...

Comment: What you do when user select a different board from the client side? HandleRouteChange is to read the value, how do you change the url?

Comment: Hi Ranu, to change to a different board the user clicks a `<Link/>` imported from `'next/link'`. The link has an `href` of `/board/${board.id}`, which routes to `src/pages/board/[boardId].js.` The `[boardId].js` page is where I am trying to detect the route change and react to it.

Answer (score 1):

How I have done this is -

Suppose I have a page called localhost:3000/board

I have done this with state, and not with [boardId] (lets called this state as boardId and initialvalue be null)

Suppose a user from anywhere in the app visit this page, using the Link

```
       <Link href="/board">
         Go To Board
       </Link>
```

on the page mount I try to read the value of boardId from url such as -

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query && router.query.boardId )
      { 
        setBoardId(router.query.boardId);
      }
   }, []);
```

and if fount I set the state of boardId,  also I do this to get the data from API

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (boardId) getBoardIdDataFromApi();
  }, [boardId] );
```

**In the above Case the board Id will be null as I'm not passing any Id** as params to the url. (In my case I create a new board here)

Case 2 - suppose a User visit this board page with something like this, from anywhere in the page -

```
      <Link
         href={{
          pathname: "/board",
          query: { boardId: boardId },
          }}
       >
```

this time url will be like

```
localhost:3000?boardId=AnyBoardId
```

and this will load the Id and get actual data from the api, or change the layout accodringingly.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query && router.query.boardId )
      { 
        setBoardId(router.query.boardId);
      }
   }, []);
```

Case - 3

Now when a user change the boaardId fromt being on the page itself, you can do -

```
  const onChangeBoard = (v) => {
    router.push('/board?boardId=${v}', undefined, { shallow: true })
    setboardId(v);
  }
```

This will upadte the state of boardId and fetch the data once the user chooses a different board and update the url.

- I'm experimenting with {shallow:true}, and I have all the data fetching mechanisms on the client side.

For you -

1. you can block getServerSideProps for Case 1
2. Use getServerSideProps for case 2
3. For case 3, if you  remove shallow, you can again use getServerSideProps but please verify.

**This may not be the exact answer. but can help you to understand the logic**

Comment: a thought, instead of link can you do a router.push to a different boardId and check what happens ?  keeping you login same.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. They helped me to figure out the solution I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got this working by checking the effect to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function handleRouteChange() {
      const { boardId } = router.query
      const { board, tasks } = await handleFetchData({ boardId })
      dispatch(hydrateTasks({ board, tasks }))
    }
    handleRouteChange()
  }, [router])
```

Here is the complete code for the page now:

```
// src/pages/board/[boardId].js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import supabase from 'Utilities/SupabaseClient'
import Board from 'Components/Screens/Board/Board'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import axios from 'axios'
import { getBaseUrl } from 'Utilities'
import { hydrateTasks } from 'Redux/Reducers/TaskSlice'

const BoardPage = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    async function handleRouteChange() {
      const { boardId } = router.query
      const { board, tasks } = await handleFetchData({ boardId })
      dispatch(hydrateTasks({ board, tasks }))
    }
    handleRouteChange()
  }, [router])

  return (
    <Board {...props}/>
  )
}

const handleFetchData = async ({boardId, req}) => {
  const baseUrl = getBaseUrl(req)
  return axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/board/${boardId}`)
    .then(({data}) => data)
    .catch(err => { console.log(err)})
}

export async function getServerSideProps ({ query, req }) {
  const { user } = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req)
  if (!user) {
    return { props: {}, redirect: { destination: '/signin' } }
  }

  const { boardId } = query
  const { board, tasks}  = await handleFetchData({boardId, req})
  return { props: { user, board, tasks } }
}

export default BoardPage
```

Comment: Does this approach generateas a static html pages id wise? after first visit.